# Problema ao colocar Aplicação feita em Laravel 5.2 em produção

Tags: apache, laravel-5

Não estou colocar meu sistema em produção.
Criei um VirtualHost no arquivo `http.conf` do Apache com a seguinte configuração:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dna/public
ServerName www.dna.com
<Directory "/var/www/html/dna/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Quando acesso o endereço **www.dna.com** a página inicial aparece normalmente, porém quando tento fazer login aparece `erro 500`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo `.htaccess` da pasta `/public` do projeto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Em que diretorio tem esse .htaccess? Tem a certeza que o caminho está bem?

Comment: Esse código não é de nenhum .`htaccess`. Está no `httpd`.conf do Apache

Comment: Ha ok, eu quando coloco um Laravel em produção faço um .htaccess na pasta root do laravel

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o .htaccess da pasta public. Se for outro arquivo que você faz, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta para ficar melhor formatado, se não ajudar eu retiro

Comment: E se aceder a www.dna.com/public?

Comment: Diz que a pasta public não existe

Comment: Configurou o arquivo `hosts`?

Comment: sim, o problema acontece da página inicial do sistema pra frente